# Excel String lookup within String

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, formula, partial-matches

[image]

i have list of "Place of receipt", i need to lookup with another column with set of list that contains City names in Proper case/ Proper name.

i tried below formula but i did not found any luck

=(VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($I$1:$I$7,A2),$I$1:$I$7),$I$1:$I$7,1,0))

it gives me result when the first word from cell matches with another one, but it will throw error when "place of receipt" has different word after first word,

for example "BRADFORD GB" will not get "Bradford, WYK" from city list as shown in above image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came across a solution to find string before comma and space, if the first word matches it will check the word (+3) which is after the comma. the result is now expected.

The formula i used :

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH((LEFT(A2,(FIND(",",A2,1)+3))),$I$1:$I$8,1),$I$1:$I$8),$I$1:$I$8,1,0),(VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH((LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))),$I$1:$I$8,1),$I$1:$I$8),$I$1:$I$8,1,0)))
```

Solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to capture the first word of the cell (or the entire word if it only contains one word):

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),A2)
```

You can use that to perform a VLOOKUP, if your current formula fails:

```
=IFERROR([your-current-formula],VLOOKUP(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),A2),1,1)
```

Comment: A few things to consider: Look at how this will potential raise false positives for `LAKEWOOD`. Also, what if a city is called "LAS VEGAS" or "NEW YORK". Searching for the 1st space might not be problemfree in a larger dataset.

Comment: Correct, but OP was looking for a solution to find a match for 'the first string', and I believe means 'the first word' in this context. It is just a fitting solution for the given data.

I would consider adding a column to the City-data, like State. This allows you to create a better query, and to minimize problems like JvdV mentioned

Comment: @JanWillem, the first formula i already tried this will match the first word from City list, 
if there is LAKEWOOD, NJ, U.S.A., 14750 then it will give me "Lakewood, NY" from list. and for the second formula the result is same as image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have office excel 365, you can use combination of xlookup and Find function to solve as below

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","@",2))-1),LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1))&"*",$D$2:$D$7,$D$2:$D$7,"Not found",2)
```

The result was obtained as below

[image: Result]

Explanation

1. First we need to extract the characters upto the second iteration of ","

   `LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","@",2))-1)`
2. Since not all strings have Names with "," example : BRADFORD GB, the above formula will throw error to counter that we use IFERROR function. So, if the above formula throws error we are going to extract only characters upto first instance of space.

   `IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","@",2))-1),LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1))`
3. Now we just need to Lookup the name on the list of cities. However since Place of Receipt and List of cities are not exactly the same, we are going to use wildcard "*" as in the overall formula on the top.

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","@",2))-1),LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1))&"*",$D$2:$D$7,$D$2:$D$7,"Not found",2)
```